# MS Word VBA Calculating Time In and Time Out in table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working on a start time and end time table with drop down list content controls. I am trying to figure out how to calculate the total hours worked depending on the selections in the Time In list and Time Out list. There's a slight catch because I have a command buttons to add and delete rows of the table so that only what's necessary is shown instead of having a ton of unused rows in the table.

Each time is in 1/4 hour intervals and I'm trying to get the result to be formatted so that 0:15 is 0.25, 0:30 is 0.50, etc.

One more thing regarding the time drop down lists. Youll notice in the code how many entries there are for each drop down list. Is there a way to make this more efficient or is that really the only way to have each item listed? It's crazy long.

Thanks so much in advance!

```
Sub MakeLaborRow(oTable As Table)
Dim oNewRow As Row
Dim oRng As Range
Dim oCell As Cell
Dim iCell As Integer
Dim oCC As ContentControl, oCC1 As ContentControl, oCC2 As ContentControl
Dim lngCell1 As Long, lngCell2 As Long
lngCell1 = 0: lngCell2 = 0
If Not ActiveDocument.ProtectionType = wdNoProtection Then
    ActiveDocument.Unprotect
End If
Set oNewRow = oTable.Rows.Add
oNewRow.Range.Font.Bold = False
For iCell = 1 To 6
    Set oCell = oNewRow.Cells(iCell)
    Set oRng = oCell.Range
    oRng.End = oRng.End - 1
    Select Case iCell
        Case 1
            Set oCC = oRng.ContentControls.Add _
                      (Range:=oRng, _
                       Type:=wdContentControlDate)
            With oCC
                .SetPlaceholderText , , "Select Date"
                .DateDisplayFormat = "ddd MM/dd/yyyy"
                .Tag = "Date" & oCell.RowIndex
            End With
        Case 2
            Set oCC = oRng.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlDropdownList)
            With oCC
                .SetPlaceholderText , , "Choose Description"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "Labor Time"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "Travel Time"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "Wait Time"
                .Tag = "Description" & oCell.RowIndex
            End With
        Case 3
            Set oCC = oRng.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlDropdownList)
            With oCC
                .SetPlaceholderText , , "Time In  "
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "12:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "12:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "12:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "12:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "1:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "1:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "1:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "1:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "2:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "2:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "2:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "2:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "3:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "3:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "3:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "3:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "4:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "4:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "4:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "4:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "5:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "5:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "5:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "5:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "6:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "6:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "6:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "6:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "7:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "7:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "7:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "7:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "8:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "8:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "8:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "8:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "9:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "9:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "9:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "9:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "10:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "10:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "10:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "10:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "11:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "11:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "11:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "11:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "12:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "12:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "12:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "12:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "1:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "1:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "1:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "1:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "2:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "2:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "2:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "2:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "3:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "3:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "3:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "3:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "4:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "4:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "4:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "4:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "5:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "5:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "5:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "5:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "6:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "6:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "6:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "6:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "7:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "7:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "7:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "7:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "8:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "8:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "8:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "8:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "9:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "9:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "9:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "9:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "10:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "10:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "10:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "10:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "11:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "11:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "11:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "11:45 PM"
                .Tag = "TimeIn" & oCell.RowIndex
            End With
        Case 4
            Set oCC = oRng.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlDropdownList)
            With oCC
                .SetPlaceholderText , , "Time Out"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "12:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "12:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "12:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "12:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "1:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "1:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "1:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "1:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "2:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "2:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "2:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "2:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "3:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "3:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "3:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "3:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "4:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "4:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "4:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "4:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "5:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "5:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "5:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "5:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "6:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "6:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "6:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "6:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "7:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "7:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "7:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "7:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "8:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "8:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "8:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "8:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "9:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "9:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "9:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "9:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "10:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "10:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "10:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "10:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "11:00 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "11:15 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "11:30 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "11:45 AM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "12:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "12:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "12:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "12:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "1:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "1:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "1:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "1:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "2:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "2:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "2:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "2:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "3:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "3:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "3:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "3:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "4:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "4:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "4:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "4:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "5:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "5:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "5:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "5:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "6:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "6:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "6:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "6:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "7:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "7:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "7:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "7:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "8:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "8:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "8:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "8:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "9:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "9:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "9:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "9:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "10:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "10:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "10:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "10:45 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "11:00 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "11:15 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "11:30 PM"
                .DropdownListEntries.Add "11:45 PM"
                .Tag = "TimeOut" & oCell.RowIndex
            End With
        Case 5
            Set oCC = oRng.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlText)
            With oCC
                .SetPlaceholderText , , "Total Hrs."
                .Tag = "TotalHrs" & oCell.RowIndex
            End With
        Case 6
            Set oCC = oRng.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlText)
            With oCC
                .SetPlaceholderText , , "---"
                .Tag = "Mileage" & oCell.RowIndex
            End With
     End Select
Next iCell
oNewRow.Cells(1).Select
ActiveDocument.Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True, _
Password:=""

lbl_Exit:
Set oCell = Nothing
Set oCC = Nothing
Set oCC1 = Nothing
Set oCC2 = Nothing
Set oRng = Nothing
Set oTable = Nothing
Set oNewRow = Nothing
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this and calling it when you need to calculate the difference in hours as a decimal.

```
Sub TimeConversion()

Dim strStart As String
Dim strEnd As String
Dim starttime As Variant
Dim endtime As Variant
Dim SplitStart
Dim SplitEnd
Dim StartResult As Long, EndResult As Long
Dim HoursWorked As Long

strStart = "9:00 AM"
strEnd = "5:00 PM"

'''''''
starttime = Left(strStart, Len(strStart) - 3)
SplitStart = Split(starttime, ":")
StartResult = SplitStart(0) + ((SplitStart(1) * 100) / 60) / 100

'''''''
endtime = Left(strEnd, Len(strEnd) - 3)
SplitEnd = Split(endtime, ":")
EndResult = (SplitEnd(0) + ((SplitEnd(1) * 100) / 60) / 100) + 12

HoursWorked = (EndResult - StartResult)
'MsgBox HoursWorked

End Sub
```

Comment: Could I just insert this into a ContentControlOnExit?